# Unable to browse to spring boot application using embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, embedded-tomcat-8

I am working on a rather large MVC project that used to run (perfectly) with just spring MVC, not spring boot.  I have finished converting it to spring boot and it runs perfectly in Netbeans and when run as a standalone JAR outside of Netbeans on my development machine.

I transported the JAR file to its destination server and everything starts normally according to the console, I get this message: `Tomcat started on the port(s): 8081 (HTTP) with context path '/MDHIS'`.  However, I am unable to browse to it as I would on my machine with the following URL: `http://localhost:8081/MDHIS/`.

I set tomcat to debug mode and it logs some interesting things :

```
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.269] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
: JspEngine --> /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.270] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:        ServletPath: /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.270] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:           PathInfo: null
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.272] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:           RealPath: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat- 
docbase.4901819852507265388.8080\WEB-INF\views\login.jsp
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.273] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:         RequestURI: /MDHIS/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.274] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:        QueryString: null
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.275] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[jsp]                    
:  Disabling the response for further output
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.277] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost]                  
: Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.315] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
: JspEngine --> /WEB-INF/views/error.jsp
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.315] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:        ServletPath: /WEB-INF/views/error.jsp
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.316] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:           PathInfo: null
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.317] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:           RealPath: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat- 
docbase.4901819852507265388.8080\WEB-INF\views\error.jsp
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.318] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:         RequestURI: /MDHIS/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.319] o.a.j.s.JspServlet                       
:        QueryString: null
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.319] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[jsp]                    
:  Disabling the response for further output
[WEBCLIENT] [DEBUG] [2018-10-15 14:44:26.320] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[. 
[dispatcherServlet]      :  Disabling the response for further output
```

I watched the docbase folder and no JSPs or classes are ever added to it.  I am having mixed results of this working or not on different environments / OSes / networks.  Has any one ever seen this behavior?

******EDIT******

POM.xml files as requested :

Common project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
<artifactId>MDHIS_Common</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!--JAVA-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--SPRING-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!--MICROSOFT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--HIBERNATE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--HAPI-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v26</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v25</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v24</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v231</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v23</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v22</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v21</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>MDHIS_Common</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Web client :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
<artifactId>MDHIS_WebClient</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<!--<packaging>war</packaging>-->

<name>MDHIS_WebClient</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!--JAVA-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--GLASSFISH-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--TOMCAT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--JASPER REPORTS-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--SIGAR-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--LOG4J2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--YASSON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--MDHIS_COMMON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
        <artifactId>MDHIS_Common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>java.net-Public</id>
        <name>Maven Java Net Snapshots and Releases</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>yasson-snapshots</id>
        <name>Yasson Snapshots repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/yasson-snapshots</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

***CONCLUSION***

Thanks to everyone that helped!  Although it was working fine on some systems when packaged as a JAR file, the change to a WAR file is what fixed it.  I can sadly no longer run the project in Netbeans because it fails to recognize that a Tomcat server is embedded within itself but everything works perfectly when using java -jar on 2 systems (Windows Server 2016 and Ubuntu LTS 18.04) that were previously not working.

Thanks

Comment: What is "the destination server"? That's not usually localhost.

Comment: just a server we have in our environment, SRV2012 with local MSSQL instance.  I am trying to browse to it from itself so indeed it would be localhost.  I tried from another machine with the IP address and that won't work either.

Comment: Update.  For some reason everything works fine under Ubuntu 18.04.  I tried a few other Windows VMs (Server 2016, 2012, Windows 10) and I have the same issue under all of them.

Comment: Yet my dev machine is Windows 10 and it works perfectly there too...

Comment: If that makes any difference, i tried NIO, NIO2 and APR (with native tomcat library).  All 3 work fine on my windows 10 machine and on my Ubuntu VM but give me the same issue when deployed somewhere else.

Comment: Smells like a firewall.

Comment: i thought the same too, until i saw it do the same thing on a Server 2016 VM at home.  All the firewalls are turned off.  This makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe a stupid remark but most of the time strange errors come from stupid mistakes. Did you define the environment variable "MDHIS_HOME" on all your servers ? Without working directory EOFException makes sense. And the fact it works on your computer and your vm (systems you own) tends to prove you got a configuration missing on other computers

Comment: The app doesn't even make it past Spring Boot initializing if the environment variable isn't there since it's used to locate the global config file.  The working directory is always CREATED but when it doesn't work there are no JSPs and classes in it.  I do not know if this is a cause or a consequence however, all users have full control over the whole folder.  This is quite baffling and all I have to work with is a (pretty much) meaningless exception...

Comment: How is the deployment log? Sometimes, i face this deployment errors but the folder still exist in tomcat home.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no deployment log since this is Tomcat embedded

Comment: The docbase folders ends with 8080, perhaps that is an issue? What does the corresponding debug log look like on your Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I have changed ports numerous times during troubleshooting, the log extract is from when the port was 8080

Comment: Can you show the exact error log ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faced with such kind of problem, I would probe what could be environmental differences between local machine (where the app is running fine) and server (where the same app is giving problem). First few things I would check are as follows:

1. Check if the JSP's are getting compiled to the work directory of Tomcat.
2. Check JAVA_HOME variable picked up by Tomcat.
3. Check if the JDK (and not just JRE) is indeed installed on the machine.
4. Check if the Java version configured for Tomcat is supported by Spring Boot version used.
5. Check the dependencies in the effective pom that have the scope
   "provided", "runtime" or "system".

But first and foremost, please refer these [JSP Limitations with Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) and note that you need to **use a war packaging -- JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar**. This executable war will work when launched with `java -jar`, and will also be deployable to any standard container.

To create a war packaging, include `<packaging>war</packaging>` in the pom where the artifact ID is declared.

You may find this [Spring Boot JSP sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) useful. This [another sample](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/) may also be helpful.

Hope the above inputs lead to a solution.

Comment: You mean you can run a WAR file as a standalone executable without using an external servlet container?  I did not know that.  Neither did i know that JSPs were not supported in a JAR file with an embedded server, never even thought of checking this since it actually works in some places.  I guess i'll try a WAR file.

Comment: When i package it as a war file, it tries to use the tomcat container i have installed on my PC even if i remove it from Netbeans.  It's like it fails to recognize that it's actually embedded in the app.

Comment: Could you share your pom please?

Comment: My solution actually consists of 3 projects : a common project where all the libraries used by the 2 other projects are declared (spring, hibernate and Microsoft MSSQL JDBC driver mostly), a web client (which is where i'm having the issue) and a standalone service.  Both the latter have their own dependencies and also the first project as a dependency which brings in what i've enumerated for them.  I will try to add them to my original post but it may be too long.

Comment: POM.xml files added!

Comment: Only the "effective" pom of the web client is what needs to be looked into. Web client pom seems to be missing two important dependencies -- 'spring-boot-starter-web' and 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'.  It may be worth spending some time studying the minimalistic Spring Boot JSP sample (linked in the answer) to clear any gaps in understanding around the use of Spring Boot dependencies.

Comment: The Spring Boot Web dependency is in the common project, which is included in the web project.  Again, everything works perfectly on my machine, both when running in Netbeans and when running the jar file outside of Netbeans.  It also works perfectly on some other machines so even though Spring Boot aparently doesn't support JSPs i've had lots of proof that it CAN work.

Comment: The common project is not a web project; as such it shouldn't have 'spring-boot-starter-web' as its dependency. The web client project is a web project; as such it should have 'spring-boot-starter-web' as its direct (and not transitive) dependency.

Comment: I understand for sure.  I did it this way to avoid repeating dependencies in the 2 other projects but I think it might be time for me to separate things properly.  I will only leave in the common project what it actually needs and i will cascade the correct spring dependencies downwards as well.  I doubt this has anything to do with my issue but it's been bugging me for a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182036/discussion-between-sanjeev-sachdev-and-martin).

Comment: Changed the packaging to war and, although the resulting file can only be run with java -jar and will not actually work from Netbeans (it doesn't recognize that a Tomcat server is embedded inside of itself), the website now works perfectly on the systems I was having issues with, without doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms described sounds as if the classLoader is not initializing the SpringBoot application class. SpringBoot starts Tomcat with the provided configs first (and this generally always works), and then attempts to start the SpringBoot Application itself. If the classLoader fails the "the website won't load" comes next.

Two things you can check for:

1) Do you use `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`? Don't because it doesn't support SpringBoot structure (nested jars).

2) Are you using `java.util.Logging` anywhere in your application? Don't because it uses `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`

You can read more about this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-restrictions

I suppose there is a third;

3) check version compatibility of dependencies (since this is MVC to Boot)
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Best of luck.

Comment: I use LOG4J2 everywhere and as far as i can remember i do not use ClassLoader anywhere.  One thing worth mentioning is that i've managed to make it work perfectly on 2 machines that were previously not working by installing Netbeans on them and running the project through the IDE.  One i build the jar file with Netbeans on the machine the resulting jar will also work perfectly there when a jar generated on my machine did not work previously.

Comment: This is interesting from NB SpringBoot plugin release notes: **Add Spring Boot dependencies (dependency metadata is taken from the Spring Initializr web service)**. Sounds like NB is updating your dependencies - perhaps from a different source? (are you using Nexus?)

Comment: These VMs do NOT have internet access so i don't see how they could be updating anything.  To make it work i uploaded the latest JDK, the Netbeans installer and my whole local Maven repository.  I run the project and it works fine, clean and build and the resulting jar works perfectly as well.  This is completely baffling.

Comment: No odd platform specific requirements? it seems it works cross-platform only after what you just said.

Comment: i put the sigar.dll or sigar.so file in the right place for the JVM to pick it up and aside from that it is completely platform independent indeed.  Since i've seen it work and not work on both Windows and Linux i've pretty much ruled out the OS itself.

Comment: OK. Back to what led me to my conclusion: _I am unable to browse to it_ | _no JSPs or classes are ever added_| _working directory is always CREATED but when it doesn't work there are no JSPs and classes in it_ | _and all I have to work with is a (pretty much) meaningless exception)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181964/discussion-between-martin-and-randy-casburn).

Answer (score 0):

This is less an answer and more of a path that should lead to eventual success.  I would start with a sample "Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat" project.  [Dev Zone has one here.](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-example)  [Another example is here.](https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-mvc-example)  While those are far too long to include here, any other working sample should be fine as well.

Get that running in your environment that currently fails.

Next, add your specifics.  If you can do this in separate 'chunks' that would be even better as you can then see what part you add breaks things.

Finally, I echo Randy's first thought in his reply - this is likely a classpath issue.